Show that the only $f$- invariant probability measure is the delta measure at $0.$
Here is the question I am trying to think about:
Let $X$ be the open unit disk in $\mathbb C$ and let $f: X \to X$ be given by $f(z) = z^2.$ Use Poincaré recurrence to show that the only $f$- invariant probability measure is the delta measure at $0.$
I am not sure how to start, can anyone give me some hints?
I am still writing the definition of each term.

Let $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure on $X$ and suppose that $\mu$ is $f$-invariant.
By Poincare recurrence, for any Borel set $E\subset X$, we have that
$$\mu\bigg(\bigcup_{N=1}^\infty\bigcap_{n\ge N}\{x\in E: f^n(x)\not\in E\}\bigg)=0$$
Let $r\in\mathbb{N}$ and set $E_r:=\{x\in X: |x|\ge \frac{1}{r}\}$. Note that $\bigcup_{N=1}^\infty\bigcap_{n\ge N}\{x\in E_r: f^n(x)\not\in E_r\}=E_r$ ( indeed, for $x\in E_r$ we have $f^n(x)\to0$, so there is some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|f^n(x)|<1/r$ for all $n\ge N$). Therefore
$$\mu(E_r)=\mu\bigg(\bigcup_{N=1}^\infty\bigcap_{n\ge N}\{x \in E_r: f^n(x)\not\in E_r\}\bigg)=0$$
Now $X\setminus\{0\}=\bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{N}}E_r$, so $\mu(X\setminus\{0\})=0$, i.e. $\mu(\{0\})=1$, i.e. $\mu$ is the Dirac mass at $0$.

do you recommend elementary books for learning this kind of Dynamics?

@Intuition I'm not the right person to ask for this, sorry!

Can you please explain the intuition behind the first equality you stated? Why should $f^n(x) \notin E$? Why you are taking $n\geq N$? Why do we have union and then intersection?

@Intuition this is precisely what Poincare recurrence tells you: you can read this equation as follows: for any Borel set $E \subset X$, the measure of the points of $E$ that have $f$-translates that eventually stop landing back in $E$ is zero. Equivalently, almost every point of $E$ has $f$-translates that will keep appearing back in $E$, not all of them, but infinitely many of them will be in $E$, no matter how far out you go, a translate that is further down will be in $E$ -- i.e. almost every point of $E$ is recurrent

What is the shape of $E_r$? Are we in an annulus?

how that we are in a unit disk showed in your solution?

@Intuition If $|z|\ge1$ then $f(f(f(...(f(z))...)))$ will not converge to zero

are the motion spiral as we continue applying $f$?

What is the intuition of taking the radius of $E_r$ like this?

@Intuition yes it's an annulus. I don't know what you mean about the spiral motion. I explained enough about the intuition, you can take it form here

Should not we prove that this is actually is the delta measure?

@Hope what did we prove?

I mean it is zero outside the singleton set and one inside it? Should not we prove this? And also how you showed that it is the only measure? I admired your answer :) that is why I am thinking about some minute details that might be missing (if I understand correctly).
